# How to group tokens placed in different positions using pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a simple sentence - "*tok0,084040,tok1,tok2,231108*" where **084040** is time (08:40:40) and **231108** is date (23.11.2008)

Following the pyparsing documentation I've written the rules to parse the tokens:

    `from pyparsing import *
    d = Literal(',').suppress()
    two_digits = Word(nums, exact=2)
    tok0 = Word(nums)
    time_token = two_digits("hour") + two_digits("min") + two_digits("sec")
    tok1 = Word(alphas)
    tok2 = oneOf('A B C')
    date_token = two_digits("day") + two_digits("month") + two_digits("year")
    grammar = (tok0 + d + time_token + d + tok1 + d + tok2 + d + date_token)`

What I want is to have a logical group in my **ParseResults** consisting of **time_token** and **date_token** so that I could use **setParseAction**, **setResultsName** for the group. Something like `Group(time_token + date_token)` considering they are not adjacent. 
`dreamGroup = Group(time_token + date_token)("datetime").setParseAction(myFn)
parseResults = grammar.parseString("123,084040,ABC,A,231108")
datetime = parseResults.datetime`
P.S.: The result of the grammar.parseString should be an instance of ParseResults.

Comment: You mean `08:40:40` right?

Comment: Sure. I'll fix it in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add results names in the body of a parse action, and they will remain with the parsed tokens.

```
def addDateTimeResults(tokens):
    tokens['date'] = ('20'+tokens.year, tokens.month, tokens.day)
    tokens['time'] = (tokens.hour, tokens.min, tokens.sec)
    tokens['datetime'] = ParseResults([tokens.date, tokens.time])
    for name in ('date', 'time'):
        tokens['datetime'][name] = tokens[name]
grammar.setParseAction(addDateTimeResults)
```

Now in your sample code, add a call to `dump()` to see what you get:

```
parseResults = grammar.parseString("123,084040,ABC,A,231108")
datetime = parseResults.datetime
print datetime.dump()
```

And you get:

```
[('2008', '11', '23'), ('08', '40', '40')]
- date: ('2008', '11', '23')
- time: ('08', '40', '40')
```

Or instead of inserting and returning tuples, you can construct an actual Python datetime object, and return that instead:

```
import datetime
def addDateTimeResults(tokens):
    dtfields = map(int, (tokens[fld] for fld in "year month day hour min sec".split()))
    # adjust 2-digit year for 21st century
    dtfields[0] += 2000
    tokens['datetime'] = datetime.datetime(*dtfields)
```

Now `print parseResults.datetime` gives:

```
2008-11-23 08:40:40
```

which is the default string representation of a Python datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

Changing parseResults on grammar level solved the problem. So I slightly midified you answer and it worked like a charm.

```
def changeGrammarParseResults(s, loc, toks):
    toks['datetime_8601'] = datetime.datetime(
        toks.pop('year'), toks.pop('month'), toks.pop('day'),
        toks.pop('hour'), toks.pop('minute'), toks.pop('second'),
        tzinfo=pytz.utc).isoformat()
```

Comment: You should move this to your question. You should avoid "thank you" answers.

Comment: Nice, I forgot about ParseResults supporting `pop()`. Does this handle adding 2000 to the 2-digit year? Are you converting the numeric strings for year, month, day, etc. to ints somewhere else now? (easily done by adding a parse action to the `two_digits` expression)

Comment: Yes, I ommitted some code (converting strings to ints, adding 2000 to year, etc) to focus on the problem. And yes, I did it by adding addParseAction to two_digits)) Thank you for pyparsing and your help!